# Making column reference via slicer

Tags: powerbi

I have a table with two choices 'FLOW_CONTEXT' and 'TEST_NAME'.

[image]

I want to let the user select one of these values using a slicer.  I then want to have a calculated formula point to either the 'FLOW_CONTEXT' or the 'TEST_NAME' column in another table.  There is a 1:1 relationship between the 'FLOW_CONTEXT' and the 'TEST_NAME' columns in the table.

Here is the column formula I have, which always defaults to false, even though the `SELECTEDVALUE` part of the `IF` statement does work (checked via a card):

```
COLUMN_POINTER = IF(
    SELECTEDVALUE(TEST_NAME_FIELD[TEST_NAME_FIELD]) = "FLOW_CONTEXT",
    CCD_BINNING_TEST_RESULTS_LAST_RANK[FLOW_CONTEXT],
    CCD_BINNING_TEST_RESULTS_LAST_RANK[TEST_NAME]
)
```

I have tried doing this with a measure but measures only see non-categorical columns.  Thx much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Columns are only calculated at refresh time - they do not respond to slicers filters in this way. You cannot re-calculate a column based on a selected value in a table visual.

You need to transform your use-case into a measure-friendly approach.